# Caching for a custom pytorch dataset

Tags: python, audio, deep-learning, pytorch, data-augmentation

I am creating a custom pytorch dataset to train an audio classification system.
Since some of the transformations applied during training as data augmentation are computationally demanding (e.g. pitch shift audio data), I would like to add a cache to my dataset to speed up the training. HDF5 seems to be the recommended option for this task.

Basically, in each training loop, I need to search the cache. If a sample with certain augmentation parameters has already been calculated the sample will be loaded from the cache, otherwise it will be calculated and cached. How should I structure the HDF5 file to do that?

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Comment: I suggest you pre-generate the augmented samples in that case. I understood your original intention as "have [data loader](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/data.html#torch.utils.data.DataLoader) read the HDF, apply transformations and if they aren't there yet, dump them to the same HDF". If so, you'd have a multiple reader/multiple writer scenario for your HDF. It's a really messy scenario in general and HDFs are not suitable for that.

Comment: I would avoid pre-generating everything as this would force me into a specific pre-processing setup (i.e. STFT parameters, silence removal etc.). Maybe caching on disk (a single file for each sample) is a better option?